# What is the right way to handle form variable

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

SpringMVC provides powerful annotation to handle JSP form data by passing data into a form bean (or POJO) whose fields are match up with the variables in the JSP form. I am creating a history record retrieval function based on user input. In JSP, every search criteria is match up with my Hibernate "history record" POJO, except the time range criteria. In such situation, I can not map my JSP form to my Hibernate POJO because there is no time range field in the POJO. Should I create a form bean to include the time range or is there another way that I can use my hibernate POJO directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could

- create another POJO extending your original POJO and adding those two fields
- create another POJO wrapping your original POJO, and use nested properties (`historyRecord.foo`, `historyRecord.range`, etc.)
- add two arguments to your request handling method, annotated with @RequestParam (see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-ann-requestparam)

Comment: can you give me one concrete example for the last option? In JSP, I can only use one form to submit data. How do I tell spring to separate the two time-range fields from the POJO

Comment: public String processSubmit(@RequestParam("startOfRange") Date startOfRange, @RequestParam("endOfRange") Date endOfRange, @ModelAttribute HistoryRecord record)